# Only writing one line to my SQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to move a row from one table to another but its not working. It does the fist line fine but then nothing I can get the rest to echo out ok just not go in to my DB.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM coffees WHERE id='$id'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO coffeeorder(coffeetype,topping,shots,milk,size,price) VALUES ('coffeetype', 'topping', 'shots', 'milk', 'Size', 'price')");

  echo $row['coffeetype'] . " " . $row['topping']." " . $row['shots']." " . $row['milk']." " . $row['size']." $" . $row['price']."<br />";

  $totalPrice = $totalPrice + $row['price'];
}
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Full code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["id"])){

$id = $_SESSION["id"];
$name = $_SESSION["name"];


}else {header('Location: index.php');}

 include_once "dbcon.php";
    $totalPrice = 0;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM coffees WHERE id='$id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

      mysql_query("INSERT INTO `coffeeorder`(`coffeetype`,`topping`,`shots`,`milk`,`size`,`price`) VALUES ('".$row['coffeetype']."', '".$row['topping']."', '".$row['shots']."', '".$row['milk']."', '".$row['size']."', '".$row['price']."')");




  echo $row['coffeetype'] . " " . $row['topping']." " . $row['shots']." " . $row['milk']." " . $row['size']." $" . $row['price']."<br />";

  $totalPrice = $totalPrice + $row['price'];

  }
    echo "Total Price $".$totalPrice;


?>
```

Comment: Select the row, insert the row and delete the row - what is the problem?

Comment: Please avoid using `mysql_` functions in new code. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_query` in new applications. This dusty, antiquated interface can cause **severe damage** to your application if not used correctly. You need to learn [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) before you create an application so full of holes it will be cracked wide open. The newer interfaces like `mysqli` and PDO make it significantly easier to compose and execute queries, so the short amount of time it takes to learn them is well spent.

Comment: So you say you're trying to move *one row*? Why do you have a `while` loop, then? Also, are there any warnings or errors? Do you have `display_errors` turned on? What do you mean "the first line"?

Comment: no errors. the loop is there so i can move it one row at a time. open to better ways if you know any.

Comment: So just to be clear: it `echo`s out the data and gets the `$totalPrice` right, but nothing shows up in the database?

Comment: yeah the echo and $totalPrice all work but i just get the fist row in the database

Comment: Do you have a primary or unique key in the table out of `coffeetype`, `topping`, `shots`, `milk`, `size` and `price`? Also, could you please show your full code? Also also, if that's your full code, I can't see how you're getting more `echo`ed results, since `id` sounds like a primary key.

Comment: I hate to point the obvious here, but your select statement specifies id... shouldn't there only be one result?

Otherwise what's the purpose of id?

Comment: No there are more then one row with the same id in this case

Comment: fair enough. I think there's been enough hoo ha in this thread with no resolution. Time to suggest you post your data structure for both tables.

Comment: Seems to me like someone needs to read up on some basic database design principles or perhaps get someone to help with the basic design.

Answer (score 3):

Please try to move to PDO:

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM coffees WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $stmt = $db->query("INSERT INTO coffeeorder(coffeetype,topping,shots,milk,size,price) VALUES (:coffeetype, :topping, :shots, :milk, :size, :price)");
    $stmt->execute(array(':coffeetype' => $row['coffeetype'], ':topping' => $row['topping'],':shots' => $row['shots'],':milk' => $row['milk'],':size' => $row['size'],':price' => $row['price']));
    echo $row['coffeetype'] . " " . $row['topping']." " . $row['shots']." " . $row['milk']." " . $row['size']." $" . $row['price']."<br />";

    $totalPrice = $totalPrice + $row['price'];

?>
```

Comment: I had it like that and still just dose the fist row then nothing

Comment: **NO**! This is **NOT** how to compose a query. This isn't even remotely close to valid SQL.

Comment: I would guess he downvoted because you put mysql_ anything in originally. Not everyone has a choice though. Sometimes I inherit massive php projects that would take months to rewrite with no budget to do so... i think it's rude. I'm upvoting.

Comment: If you *have* to use `mysql_query` then you **MUST** use `mysql_real_escape_string`, no excuses. The original example didn't even bother to escape, it just slung values in there from a `$row` variable which meant if any of those fields contained `'` the whole thing would explode. This PDO version is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do both the insert and the select inside one query:

```
INSERT INTO `coffeeorder` (
    `coffeetype`,
    `topping`,
    `shots`,
    `milk`,
    `size`,
    `price`
)
SELECT
    `coffeetype`,
    `topping`,
    `shots`,
    `milk`,
    `size`,
    `price`
FROM `coffees`
WHERE `id`='$id'
```

However, this leads to duplicate data in multiple tables. What you should really do is set your tables up a little different and in the coffeeorder table, instead of storing all the information about a coffee, store just the id of the coffee. Then when querying out the order, you can join the coffee table and get the coffee information.

```
SELECT
   `coffee`.`coffeetype`,
   `coffee`.`topping`,
   `coffee`.`shots`,
   `coffee`.`milk`,
   `coffee`.`size`,
   `coffee`.`price`
FROM `coffeeorder`
    JOIN `coffee`
        ON `coffee`.`id`=`coffeeorder`.`coffee_id`
```

This is what databases do best (I guess other than store data).